# Is codecvt not supported by Clang or GCC?

Tags: gcc, c++11, unicode, clang, codecvt

I can't even get the basic codecvt example from cppreference.com to compile on GCC 4.9 or Clang 3.4, e.g.:

http://goo.gl/HZ5GLH

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/345d6d89949ac1e6

Comment: I think the current trunk libc++ supports codecvt properly...

Comment: Are you telling your compiler to use C++11?

Comment: Rather than being an issue of compiler version, this is down to the implementation of the standard library. libc++ has supported codecvt for a long time. For clang the flag to switch to libc++ is `-stdlib=libc++`: http://rextester.com/EPRYNU17491

Comment: And the site coliru.stacked-crooked.com does not have libc++ installed, so you can't try it there.

Comment: @barnes53 coliru does have libc++ installed http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1b8ab4ea3b8e161 (OP still has to fix the erroneous cast to unsigned char, but the command line is shown)

Comment: @Cubbi Oh, neat. That's new since the last time I tried.

Comment: @Cubbi Oh, I see the issue I had before was the -lsupc++ flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [libstdc++ manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x), part 22.4.1, it is **missing** the support for `codecvt`, even on the latest version.

And [libc++ has complete support for C++11 and C++14 features](http://libcxx.llvm.org/), so you should use it on CLang, specifying the `-stdlib=libc++` compiler flag (make sure you have it installed).

**Edit:** As of current versions of libstdc++, codecvt is now supported.

Comment: Adding this flag solved many mysterious "Implicit instantiation of undefined template std::__1::codecvt" errors I was getting on a project that built on Linux (w/ GCC) and Windows (w/ MSVC) but not on OS X (w/ Clang).